# Secure Reliable Transport (SRT) passphrase & latency parameter setting

Tags: ffmpeg, parameters, protocols, libavformat

***Hope you all are doing well.***
I am trying to set parameters like passphrase and latency in **srt url**. But, i need to know whether while setting **passphrase** parameter, is it necessary to set **pbkeylen** value also? If yes, then what is purpose of **pbkeylen** parameter in **passphrase**? or what is role in that srt url of **pbkeylen**?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/API/API-socket-options.md#srto_pbkeylen), `pbkeylen` defines the key size used for the AES encryption. It is independent of the `passphrase`.

It is not necessary to set it - it will default to 16 bytes (128 bit), or whatever the other end of the connection sends in the handshake if it has been set there.